# Java - JSONObject charset

Tags: java, json, utf-8, character-encoding, utf8-decode

I'm using JSONObject from org.json.*

I need to construct JSONObject with string fields like this

```
field:"englishletters123\u1234\u3456"//UTF-8 encoding
```

so, I'm doing this

```
myJSONObject.put("field", myString);
```

But instead of this I'm getting object with fluent (non-english) letters instead of their UTF-8 representation.

```
String newString = new String(oldString.getBytes(...), ...);
myJSONObject.put("field", newString);
```

doesn't work as well

Is there any way to make such operation? Maybe I should use some other library?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly familiar with that JSON serialization library, but since you asked, the GSON library from google is amazing. It handles nearly everything through reflection, it's as simple as creating an object that fit the description of the JSON text you are attempting to create.

for example:

```
public class Thing{
    public String field = "whatever you want";
}

Gson gson = new Gson();

String jsonString = gson.toJson(new Thing());
```

de-serializing is simple too:

```
Thing t = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Thing.class);
```

Of course, there's much more to the library, but that's the basics of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the solution of my issue. I didn't find any information about charsets in GSON wiki as well. Anyway thank you very much for your reply.